# Can a father prevent the daughter from going on holiday with the EX-wife?

Tags: european-union, family-law, divorce, italy

If a 10 years old girl is daughter of a divorced Italian couple, and an Italian court disposed for her a shared trust like 30%-70% (father - mother respectively), does the mother have the right to bring her on holiday *with somebody that the father doesn't know* in an other country without the agreement of the father?

Comment: I can see that you have tagged this as Italy. Is this because the court ruling mentioned was made in Italy, or is Italy the holiday destination? If the latter then where was the ruling made?

Comment: The court was in Italy, and the people involved are from Italy.

Comment: What rules does the divorce decree set for the daughter to spend time with people the father doesn't know? Does it set different rules in different countries?

Comment: I don't think there are different rules in different countries, but anyway how can the father be sure that the daughter is safe if she's with unknown people?

Comment: How can the mother be sure that the daughter is safe, if she's with the father? For a joined custody there has the be at least a rudimentary level of trust and the assumption that both parents mean well for their child. What specific "harm" are you worried about?

Comment: As the first thing I want to specify that I'm neither the father nor the mother. Anyway the doubt isn't about the fact that both parents mean well for their child, but if somebody else (in this case somebody that the father doesn't know) does too. There are specific laws about that or it has to be specified by the court when assigning the joined custody?

Comment: Does the Court's order specify? I suspect that the answer is "yes" at least within the E.U. and "with somebody that the father doesn't know" is almost surely irrelevant. https://www.lopsandassociates.com/child-custody/

Comment: *"with somebody that the father doesn't know" is almost surely irrelevant*  Thank you @ohwilleke, the question was exactly this one.